# Average values of a single channel

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I converted my image from rgb to YUV. Now I want to find the average values of luma channel alone. Could you please help me by telling how I can achieve this? Moreover, is there a way to determine how many channels an image consists of?

Comment: get the Length of Val in a Scalar? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907842/4721626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image.channels() will give you the number of channels in any image. Please refer to the OpenCV documentation.

multiple channels can be accessed as follows:

```
        img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] //Y
        img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] //U
        img.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] //V
```

Comment: I tried. but am not able to find a result for accessing values of a single channel. I guess am searching rong.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    vector<Mat> channels;
    Mat img = imread("Documents/forest.jpg");
    split(img, channels);
    Scalar m = mean(channels[0]);
    printf("%f\n", m[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::vector<cv::Mat> rgbChannels(3);
cv::split(inputImage, rgbChannels);

isn't this the format? Moreover, what should be the data type of m? Am facing problems there. could you please help me.?

Comment: Hi, apologies, I've been using Python too much recently that I forgotten about types haha. I've edited the code example. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the edit. :). could you please temme why you gave it as 'm[0]'?

Comment: Because the function mean(...) returns a cv::Scalar. If you have given it the entire Mat object instead of one of its channel, then each entry of m would have contained the mean for the corresponding channel. Since in this case the code only pass in 1 channel, only the first returned value in m is valid.